# Blacklist for CSRF attack

Tags: security, csrf, blacklist

I wanna create a blacklist for `CSRF` attack. For example, in `SQL injection`, keywords like: `select`, `from`, `where`, `drop` and etc, can set in a blacklist. I was wondering that is it possible to create `CSRF` attack blacklist?

Comment: but why? blacklists are known to be a dumb solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really... CSRF is a request to a real resource initiated by a browser with a real session. To somehow block it would mean blocking legit requests. The only ways are some CSRF token and checking of the origin/referer header in your web app

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that it's not possible to implement a blacklist for CSRF as daniel f. noted, because there is no distinctive input at all, blacklist filters are in general known to be a very weak control. They are often insufficient even against SQL injection, which should be one of the easiest to protect against by blacklists because of the strict language and relatively small set of keywords.

OWASP states with regard to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection): "As is almost always the case, blacklisting is riddled with loopholes that make it ineffective at preventing SQL injection attacks." The same applies to about any other blacklist.

There are several ways to prevent CSRF as described [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), but blacklisting input is not one of them.